# Sharedpreference inside an adapter class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

is it possible to implement `SharedPreference` inside an adapter class?
I have tried for a long time now, but don't know what to do. I use a recyclerview that get data from firebase. I have a `list_view` layout with one `CheckedTextView`. And it is this `CheckedTextView` I want to get the values saved.

Comment: From the `View` that is handling the RecyclerView call a method of your business class that should then call a method of a "Repository" class or something like that and this class should have access to `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`. Or if you don't care about structuring the code 
 just access `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` from your `Adapter`

Comment: @kingston If I post my code, could you show me then?

Comment: If it is about accessing shared prefs, `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` is enough. Of course to do that directly in your Activity or Fragment is not the optimal solution but that is true only if you care about your code. If you are just experimenting just call that static method to get the SharedPref. And then do whatever you want with it

Comment: Actually, I don't have a separate Adapter class. I have this `public static class ShowDataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {` in my MainActivity. And under this I have the checkedtextview etc. But when I try to put `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` in there the `(context)` is red.

Comment: the Activity is your context then. Access the instance of the activity. Again this is horrible. Do this only if you are experimenting